# Bernoulli equation and the ideal gas law for air flow in a streamtube or pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, ideal-gas, bernoulli-equation

For incompressible, inviscid, steady flow of an ideal gas in a tube, Bernoulli's principle holds:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 + \rho g z + p = \text{constant}
$$
This equation could be interpreted as saying that energy in such a flow can be exchanged between pressure, velocity, and gravitational potential energy.

My question is how temperature plays into this. If I have slow (incompressible) flow of air in a pipe and the pipe area constricts, the flow velocity will increase and the pressure will decrease. Since the density is roughly constant, the ideal gas law predicts a change in temperature as well.
$$
T_2 = p_2/(\rho R)
$$

I'm just curious if this combination/application of Bernoull's principle and the ideal gas law would be appropriate for the conditions I've described.

---

My question has already been answered in the affirmative here: [Temperature Changes in a Venturi Tube](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/298325/temperature-changes-in-a-venturi-tube)

Comment: Is an ideal gas incompressible?

Comment: No, but we frequently solve problems of the type "given $\rho_1,p_1,T_1,p_2,\rho_2$, find $T_2$." It just so happens that $\rho_1=\rho_2$ in this case.

Comment: You should be using $p=\frac NVk_BT=\frac{Nm}V\frac{k_B}mT=\rho\frac{k_B}mT$ so that you can factorise $\rho$ out everywhere and argue that an increase in $v^2$ leads to a decrease in $T$, and I think this result may be derivable from statistical mechanics. Note, however, that the pressure difference due to the constriction changes does work on the flow and thus it is not obvious how to interpret the results.

Comment: Hmm. Pressure difference implies work when there is a corresponding change in volume. Here, the flow is incompressible, so the density is constant. If we follow a fluid parcel of mass $m$ down the pipe, the density of the parcel does not change, so the volume of the parcel is constant. This would imply that the parcel gets "skinnier" and faster in the constricted section, but its volume doesn't change. So the pipe does no work on the flow. This makes sense as Bernoulli's principle is about conservation of energy in a steady flow: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle